# How to create a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`

`table1` columns

```
product_name 
product_info
```

`table2` columns

```
product_name 
product_info 
Product_address 
etc
```

I need to insert into `table1` if any new product name is inserted in `table2`

I tried below code but its not inserting. Where did I made a mistake?

```
as
begin
    insert into  table2  (product_name product_info Product_address etc) values   (...);

    INSERT INTO table1(Product_Name)
         SELECT Product_Name 
         FROM tb_new_purchase
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id )
 end
```

Comment: Are both tables empty and not inserting?

Comment: not inserting into table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery.  I find your table names inconsistent.  I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1(Product_Name)
     SELECT Product_Name 
     FROM table2
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name
                       FROM table1
                       where table1.Product_Name = Table2.Product_Name
                      );
```

Your query never inserts a new name, because there is at least one row in the query.  By the way, you can also express this as:

```
INSERT INTO table1(Product_Name)
     SELECT Product_Name 
     FROM table2
     WHERE Product_Name not in (SELECT Product_Name
                                FROM table1
                               );
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it will only insert where tb_new_product_name_id is empty.